# IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.3 64-bit --- Visibility of Network Drives in Module Settings

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea

I have set up a new project inside the aforementioned IDE on a **Windows 7 - 64-bit** machine. **I wanted to add libraries to the project. These libraries reside on a network folder.**

By clicking on the project inside the **Project Explorer** and successively **pressing F4** i managed to get into the **Module Settings**.

[image: Module Settings]

Under **Project Settings** i clicked **Libraries**, then the **Plus-sign** and **Java**.

[image: Java Libraries]

Unfortunately no network drives show up.

***How can i make the IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.3 64-bit access my network drives?***

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean when you say the files reside in a "network folder". Is the folder from a mapped network drive? I have several mapped network drives and they all show. Also, what version of Java is IDEA running under (Help > About). Updating the Java version may help. (I'm using Java 8u11) The easiest way is to set the `IDEA_JDK` and/or `IDEA_JDK_64` environment variables to the root directory of a JDK installation. Finally, although I do not recall a related bug, you can try updating to 13.1.4 that was released recently.

Comment: Network folder means: "A folder which resides on a network drive. (On Windows you can add Network Drives by clicking 'Computer ---> Add Network Drive' placed in the upper band)"

Comment: I don't mean to split hairs, but the available options are "Map a Network Drive" & "Add a Network Location...". There is a [difference](http://goo.gl/RHmRm4). If you've mapped a network drive, and thus see the network location as a Drive letter in "Computer", then you should see that in the IDEA file chooser. If you "Added a Network Location" such that your remote content shows as a resource in "My Network Places"/"Network", then you will not be able to access it w/o adding a drive mapping. If you did map a drive, try the upgrades I recommended above.

Comment: No, my network drive is a drive which has a letter-location like "X:\" or "W:\".